# Existence of an entire function having specific mapping of sequences of points

Tags: complex-analysis

let ${[{z_{n}}]}$ be sequence of complex numbers with no finite accumulation point, and let $[{w_{n}}]$ be an arbitrary sequence of complex numbers. Prove there is an entire function $f$ such that$$f(z_{n})=w_{n}$$ for all $n>=1$.

I have a feeling that this is an application of some theorems like Runge's Theorem and Little Picard theorem to which I am totally unconfortable. I was wondering if someone has better way of doing this without referring to the standard results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an application of Mittag-Leffler's theorem and the Weierstrass factorization theorem.  See e.g. Rudin, "Real and Complex Analysis", theorem 15.15.

EDIT: In order to handle the case where all but one $w_n = 0$, you're going
to need something pretty close to the Weierstrass factorization theorem. 
And given a solution $f$ of that case where all the zeros have multiplicity $1$ and there no other zeros, if you can solve the general problem you can divide by this $f$ and
have Mittag-Leffler's theorem in the case where all the poles are simple. So it
really makes sense to do this in the framework of Weierstrass and Mittag-Leffler.

Comment: which edition? The book I have( p.60 Thm 13.13) has the following: Suppose $f$ is a meromorphic function in plane open set.....
Is that what you referring to? Is there a way of doing without using those theorems?

Comment: I guess mine is the first edition, copyright 1966.  Theorem 13.13 is on page 260, not page 60.  Theorem 15.15 is on page 298.