# Existence of an entire function with certain property

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequence of complex numbers such that $|a_n|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Prove that there exists an entire function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$  (i.e. $f$ is complex differentiable on the complex plane $\Bbb C$) satisfying $f(a_n)=b_n$, for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Is there any  proof of this without using the [Mittag-Leffler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) and [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) ? As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263405/existence-of-an-entire-function-having-specific-mapping-of-sequences-of-points) (or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299818/entire-function-with-prescribed-values?rq=1)) in MSE (or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20711/does-there-exist-a-holomorphic-function-which-takes-given-values-on-the-positive) in the Mathoverflow)  are proofs using these, which I am not supposed to use. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat brute-force, but direct construction. We must require that the $a_n$s are all different, of course. Without loss of generality we can also assume that $a_n\ne 0$ for $n>0$.

We will construct a sequence of entire functions that have the right value for increasing prefixes of the $a_n$s, and then show that the functions converge to an entire function.

In step $0$, set $f_0(z)=b_0$.

In step $n$ for $n>1$, we construct $f_n$ as $f_{n-1}+g_n$, where $g_n$ is a function that is $0$ at $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ and has the right value at $a_n$ to make $f_n(a_n)=b_n$. In particular we use
$$ g_n(z)=cz^k\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(z-a_n) $$
for an appropriate constant $c$ and a $k$ chosen large enough that $\lvert g(z)\rvert \le 2^{-n} $ whenever $\lvert z\rvert \le \lvert a_n\rvert-1$.

Now, for any $D>0$, $\lvert a_n\rvert-1$ will eventually be greater in $D$, and therefore $ \lim_n f_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n $ will converge *uniformly* for $\lvert z\rvert < D$. But all of the $f_n$ are entire (in fact polynomials), and [uniform convergence on an open subset of $\mathbb C$ preserves analyticity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074205/comparison-of-the-consequences-of-uniform-convergence-between-the-real-and-compl), so the limit is analytic on $\lvert z\rvert < D$. But $D$ was arbitrary, so $\lim_n f_n$ is analytic everywhere.